# java: método que devuelva un arreglo con las posiciones del número pasado como parámetro de un arreglo da ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, array, método

Necesito que mi método me devuelva un arreglo con las posiciones del número pasado como parámetro de un arreglo el cual contiene la clase(si el número se encuentra en el arreglo), y que en caso de que el número pasado como parámetro no este en ninguna posición del arreglo me devuelva el arreglo con un sólo "-1", para así en el main validar si no lo contiene o sí si en que posiciones. A la hora de llamar el método me bota con un

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

El siguiente es el código que tengo del método, ojalá puedan ayudarme muchas gracias.

```
    public int[] consultaIndividual(int busqueda) {
    int pos = 0, pos2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
        if (numeros[i] == busqueda) {
            pos++;
        }
    }
    if (pos > 0) {
        int[] posiciones = new int[pos];
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            if (numeros[i] == busqueda) {
                posiciones[pos2] = i + 1;
                pos2++;
            }                
        }
        return posiciones;
    } else {
        int[] noHay = {-1};
        return noHay;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo haria algo así

```
private static int[] consultaIndividual(int[] numbers, int i) {
    int[] result = {-1};
    if(numbers == null || numbers.length == 0)
        return result;
    result = new int[numbers.length];
    int v = 0; 
    for(int pos = 0; pos < numbers.length; pos++) {
        if(numbers[pos] == i)
            result[v++] = pos;
    }
    if(v==0)
        return new int[]{-1};
    return java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(result, 0, v);
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, pero me sigue botando del programa con la exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: pero eso en que linea ocurre y con que parametros? Agrega mas detalle, copia todo el stacktrace y si podes  los valores que estas usando.

Comment: Ya solucioné ese problemita hermano gracias, sólo retorne null cuando estaba vacío, muchas gracias!.